# django + aws for iot logging and rendering of data

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, iot

I am planning on making a django iot project hosted on aws ec2 instance. The architecture is on the picture. The sensor's data will be read by raspberry pi 3 and will be sent to django web app (django/raspi-data/) on json format hosted on an ec2 instance by creating an api to communicate the raspberry with django. The sent data will be logged on a postgresql hosted on aws rds. For the user to be able to see the data summary, he/she will access another web app (django/client/) hosted on the same ec2 instance as the previous one. The web app will get the data from postgresql db and will be sent to the user's browser in json format. javascript then will handle how to summarize the data. The user can choose if s/he want to render the data in line graph on daily average reading of the data or in monthly basis. Also, the sampling rate of sensor will be 1 every 3 seconds. The Database design will be just date and data only.

[image: Architecture of the IoT system for reading temperature, displaying average in daily or monthly basis]

My question is, is this architecture good? or there are any problems here? if there are problems, what could be the possible solution for these?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL RDS: As you're planning to store sensory data (telemetry information / time series data) in RDS - It does not scale horizontally. Instead I would have used DynamoDB to persist such time series data.

Cloud Front - You did not mention about user base. However, if your end users are globally distributed than on top of S3, You should use Cloud Front to optimize performance.

Finally,
EC2 - I'm assuming you are not going to use the serverless architecture. However, use EC2 role whenever you need access to AWS services from EC2, in place of long term credentials (access key ID and secret access key).

IoT - You did not mention anything. But you can check AWS IoT for MQTT broker, thing and so on.

Comment: Thanks Tejas for pointing those things out. I really appreciate it. Though, I still have some questions in my mind. I am beginner on cloud technology. This system is my final project for my school. And one of my top priority is cost saving since im really broke. every penny counts.
I dont think that my project will be globally distributed and im considering of using only the given URL of the EC2 instance to access my stuff. Will there be any problem on that?

Comment: And also I am planning on giving MQTT data from Arduino sensors to raspberry pi and bundling the readings in http POST request altogether then throw it to django on EC2 instance because I cant comprehend how AWS IoT handles MQTT and I think I will be able to save some money from it if i dont use AWS IoT. will that be alright?

Comment: It's alright to use EC2 URL (public DNS) for academic project. Moreover, AWS providers free tier for 12 months once you create an account where EC2 and IoT has been mentioned as free. Please check it at https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%2312monthsfree&awsm.page-all-free-tier=4 to save your cost.